# Is use of the ASP.Net Request.QueryString safe in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xss

Consider the following code:

```
function redirect() {
    window.location = "../../index.aspx?<%=Request.QueryString%>";
}
```

Is this code safe or can it be exploited by an XSS attack?

If so:

1. How?
2. How to prevent it?

Comment: Definitely exploitable. You need to do some encoding to prevent JavaScript from being injected via the query string.

Comment: How would this be exploitable? The `'` is encoded right?

Comment: If the user takes his browser somewhere else, would that count as XSS? I don't think so. Sure this allows me to play javascript tricks, but other users should be safe.

Comment: Think of this as a querystring: xx"; $.runBadJavascript(); window.location = "whatever

Comment: @nunespascal you seem to be making a common mistake: thinking no one would send someone else a malicious link. That's the basis of many xss attacks.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, the attack value would be '%22; $.run...' which would not be exploitable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this as a querystring:

```
Xx"; alert('pwned'); window.location ="whatever
```

Basically, you are allowing completely arbitrary JavaScript to be injected.

Best solution: never take direct user input and use it this way.

Second best solution: encode it for use in a JavaScript string before using it there. A simple " breaks out here.

Also; do not mistakenly do HTML encoding for this. That won't work right and will still be vulnerable.

Comment: Umm... Request.Querystring returns the raw, unencoded string. It is **not** encoded.

Comment: @kees but it is not the ; that is your problem here; it's the "

Comment: @kees and the WebForms engine (aspx, etc) is not encoding with <%= either.